# Pandas - Transposing rows into different Dataframes

Tags: pandas, transpose

I have two rows of data. I am trying to have this transposed into two dataframes

```
col1,col2,col3
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

I am trying to perform a transpose function on the above and have this split into two data frames.

When I do a simple transpose I get the below:

```
col1,1,4
col2,2,5
col3,3,6
```

I am trying to perform a transpose based on the number of rows of data and have them split into different data frames.

Expected output:

Dataframe1:

```
col1,1
col2,2
col3,3
```

Dataframe2:

```
col1,4
col2,5
col3,6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create dictionary comprehension for dictionary of DataFrames:

```
df1 = df.T
dfs = {c: df1[[c]] for c in df1.columns}
print (dfs)
{0:       0
col1  1
col2  2
col3  3, 1:       1
col1  4
col2  5
col3  6}
```

---

```
print (dfs[0])
      0
col1  1
col2  2
col3  3

print (dfs[1])
      1
col1  4
col2  5
col3  6
```

If need extract DataFrames from original `DataFrame`:

```
print (df.loc[[0]].T)
      0
col1  1
col2  2
col3  3

print (df.loc[[1]].T)
      1
col1  4
col2  5
col3  6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `shape` of the dataframe and get the amount of columns, then use `iloc` to extract each column as a dataframe to a new list:

```
t = df.T

dfs = [t.iloc[:, x:x+1] for x in range(t.shape[1])]

print(dfs[0], '\n')
print(dfs[1])

      0
col1  1
col2  2
col3  3 

      1
col1  4
col2  5
col3  6
```